# Best practice for running a method specific to a subclass in a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, methods, foreach, subclass

I am writing some code that needs to loop through an array of objects continuously. There are several types of blocks, such as bricks, metal or sand, and I update their position and whether or not a player is touching them in one foreach loop.

The sand needs to have a method by which it falls down when the player is standing on it. What is the best way in javascript to run a method specific to the sand object from within the foreach loop?

Comment: What  do you have so far?

Comment: It sounds like the root of your problem may be a design issue. Why are you mixing unrelated object types? Or if they are related, why don't they have a common method?

Comment: Please add code and data object first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use an if statement within the forEach. For example:

```
const playerPosition = ...
const arrayOfBlocks = [ ... ]
arrayOfBlocks.forEach(block => {
    if (block.type === 'sand' && playerPosition === block.position) {
         block.fall() 
    } 
})
```

A different approach would be to just filter both the type and position. For example:

```
const playerPosition = ...
const arrayOfBlocks = [ ... ]

arrayOfBlocks
    .filter(block => block.type === 'sand')
    .filter(block => block.position === player.position)
    .forEach(block => black.fall())
```